# ImageMagick works in controllers but "not available" in queues?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, imagemagick, imagick

I've just about lost my mind trying to fix this one. I'm using ImageMagick in my controllers, and it's working okay. I've now tried to move some of those functions to a queued job, and it's now saying "ImageMagick module not available with this PHP installation."

Move them back, everything works again. Put them into a `Job`, everything breaks.

I'm not sure what context I could supply, really. I'm importing Image and Imagick the same in both the controllers and the jobs:

```
use Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic as Image;
use Imagick;

Image::configure(['driver' => 'imagick']);
```

Works fine in the controller (and helper functions), but dies here in jobs:

`$preview = Image::make($file);`

Identical code, aside from that. Is there any other info that could be of use?

Comment: have u performed a `composer dump-autoload` and `php artisan queue:restart`

Comment: I have - neither of those help.

Comment: whats ur local setup containers or simple mamp/xamp ?

Comment: Standard MAMP set-up. phpinfo() shows ImageMagick installed and working - I'd maybe guess jobs run through terminal, while controllers don't or something?

Comment: OS runs `php artisan schedule:run` behind the curtains, then everything its executed in php in background so that should not affect anything.  try again with `php artisan queue:work --tries=1` this should show you the specific errors... or use database to log the failed jobs so u can check what is exactly failing...

Comment: Isn't this pretty self-explanatory? Or does it say "not available" for reasons other than it not being available? "ImageMagick module not available with this PHP installation. {"exception":"[object] (Intervention\\Image\\Exception\\NotSupportedException(code: 0): ImageMagick module not available with this PHP installation."

Comment: yeah fair enough lost track of that. I presume you have tried to restart your services (MAMP)

Comment: Of course - to reiterate, it works perfectly in every other controller/helper, just not anything added to queues, as far as I can tell

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't have `extension=imagick.so` in the ini file being used by the PHP command line executable, but do have that in the ini file being used by the PHP webserver executable.

If you find what ini file is being used by doing `php -i | grep ini` on the command line, you'll be see what ini file needs to be edited.

Answer (score 0):

**Might Help**

If you are using a queue job with **Supervisor**.

Please check if you start your queue job with the correct php executable in **program configuration** file in **command** option section:

**command=php /path/to/your/project/artisan queue:work sqs --sleep=3 --tries=3**

it could be like this if you are using queue job with supervisor in Mac OS:

**command=/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.4.8/bin/php /path/to/your/project/artisan queue:work sqs --sleep=3 --tries=3**